# How to reload outlook add-in from typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an Outlook add-in but have a problem when the user has not consented to the scopes, a new tab opens and the add-in is "stuck" trying to process my request after it failed.
I would like to somehow reload the add-in after the user gives consent, but don't know how. Currently I tried refreshing the add-in, even though that is not the best solution, still does not work, cannot even manage to reload it.
None of these work:

```
      Office.addin.hide();
      window.location.reload();
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
      setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload()
    }, 100);
    history.go();
```

This is my method where i would like to do something if the request fails because of no consent:

```
  async getUser(token: any, needsExchange: boolean) {
    const res = await axios.post<any, AxiosResponse<any>>((process.env.APP_NAME === "outlook_local"
      ? process.env.BASE_URL_WSC
      : window.location.origin ?? process.env.BASE_URL) +
      "api",
      { AccessToken: token, Application: process.env.APP_NAME, NeedsExchange: needsExchange }
    )      .catch(function (err) {
      //  window.open(process.env.CONSENT_URL, '_blank');
      if (err.response.data.errors[0].errorCode === 65001 || err.response.data.er) {
        window.open(process.env.CONSENT_URL, '_blank');
      }
      console.log(err.response.data.info);
      NotificationManager.error(
        err.response.data.info ?? t("notifications.serverError"),
        t("notifications.error"),
        60000
      );

    });

    return (res as any).data;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to run `window.location.reload()` in Script Lab on Outlook on Windows, but using a simple use case. Try running `window.location.reload()` with a basic add-in first to verify that it works, then start implementing the complexities of your use case.